# Simple drop-in replacement for 2D arrays

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have inherited code that has a number of functions (not class members) that avoid overflowing the stack like this (note: the values are not saved over function calls, so semantically `static` is unnecessary):

```
void func()
{
    static BIGSTRUCT foo[BIGNUM];
    static BIGGERSTRUCT bar[BIGGERNUM][BIGGERNUM];
    // etc...
}
```

For the one-dimensional case, `std::unique_ptr<BIGSTRUCT []> foo(new BIGSTRUCT[BIGNUM]);` works, but is there as simple a way to solve the two-dimensional case?

Comment: They will be declared static because they were too big to go on the stack.

Comment: If the function is not re-entrant, then the existing code is simpler than a dynamic-allocation version. You can use `std::array` to get value semantics.

Comment: @M.M: The code is used by multiple threads, so it needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::unique_ptr` can be a `std::unique_ptr` to anything. Even a two-dimensional buffer.

However, for most cases of legacy code, it's better to simply replace the array with a `std::vector`, so you don't have to worry about memory leaks.

Comment: So `std::unique_ptr<BIGGERSTRUCT [BIGGERNUM][]> bar(new BIGGERSTRUCT[BIGGERNUM][BIGGERNUM]);` would work as expected?

Comment: The syntax looks slightly wrong to me, but it doesn't matter. Like I said, I would simply use a std::vector. Much simpler than a std::unique_ptr.

Comment: I do agree that `std::vector` is the correct answer, but the code I have has a **LOT** of instances of the above declarations, and I have little time to refactor...

Comment: You could write a simple template class that uses `unique_ptr` to hold a 2D array type, and overload enough operators to make it behave as if it was a 2D array.